# Using hasattr and not hasattr in python

Tags: python

I need to use python `hasattr` for my very specific purpose. I need to check that an object is having an attribute, and *not* having another attribute.

Consider the class object named `model`, I need to check that whether it is having an attribute called `domain_id`:

```
if hasattr(model, 'domain_id'):
```

I also need to check for one more condition that it shouldn't have attribute called `type`.

```
if not hasattr(model, 'type'):
```

How to combine the two checks here?

Comment: Your question title already has your answer..

Comment: Won't `if hasattr(model, 'domain_id') not hasattr(model, 'type'):` work?

Answer (score 6):

Just combine the two conditions with `and`:

```
if hasattr(model, 'domain_id') and not hasattr(model, 'type'):
```

The `if` block will only execute if both conditions are true.